# How to list all executor starved jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

On my Jenkins instance, we have a big long queue of jobs that are executor starved. How would I write a Groovy/pipeline script that would periodically query the Jenkins instance for starved jobs and kill them off?

[image: jenkins_queue]

I can list jobs with long queue times like this script code...

```
def maxQueueWaitTimeMinutes = 30 // Adjust this value to your desired threshold in minutes

Jenkins.instance.queue.items.each { item ->
    if (item.isBuildable() && isExecutorStarved(item, maxQueueWaitTimeMinutes)) {
        println("Executor-starved job: ${item.task.name}, Queue ID: ${item.id}")
    }
}

def isExecutorStarved(item, maxWaitTimeMinutes) {
    def currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    def inQueueSinceMillis = item.getInQueueSince()
    
    // Check if the job has been waiting in the queue for longer than the specified threshold
    return (currentTimeMillis - inQueueSinceMillis) > (maxWaitTimeMinutes * 60 * 1000)
}
```

But we have some very long running jobs that might wait in the queue for a long time. Since Jenkins puts the little clock symbol next to a starved job, there must be some way of querying for whether its starved.